# Laravel5での変数の渡し方について

Tags: laravel

いつもお世話になっています。
ただいま手探りでLaravel5を勉強中です。
viewへのデータの渡し方で疑問に思った事があるのですが、調べきれませんでしたので、質問させてください。

コントローラーで、

```
public function index() {
  $test = "テスト";
  return view('blog.index')->with('test',$test);
}
```

と言うように記述して変数をViewに表示してみたのですが、
例えばこれをblog.indexだけではなく、blog.showやblog.editなど、
該当コントロール下の全メソッドに共通して渡す書き方はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コンストラクタで以下のように書くと blog.index、blog.show、blog.editのviewへ渡せると思います。

```
public function __construct() {
    View::share('categories', 'カテゴリ');
}
```

Comment: 定数的な使い方を模索していたので、現段階で一番これだ！と言う回答でした。ありがとうございました！
早速試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

目的と異なるかもしれませんが、いくつかのビューで共通するテンプレートパーツを使っているのであれば[View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)が使えるかもしれません。
これはテンプレートファイルが読み込まれた際に、そのテンプレートに対して変数を渡せる機能です。

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('sidebar', function ($view) {
            $test = "テスト";
            $view->with('test', $test);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: こんな事も出来るんですね！共通するパーツが多い際に便利そうです。
今はまだ勉強中であまり複雑なものを作っていないのですが、絶対使う事が出てきそうですので、是非活用させていただきます！